# How can I start FastApi and aiogram bot in one event loop?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi, aiogram

I have code like this:

```py
app = FastAPI()
bot = Bot(token=config_data.BOT_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
```

I usually start bot in this way:
`executor.start_polling(dp)`

and start FastApi app:
`uvicorn.run(app)`

How can I start it in one event loop?

Answer (score 1):

use webhook to use fastapi and aiogram together

**bot.py file**

```
from aiogram import Dispatcher, Bot, types
TOKEN = "1945118170:AAH4ZVOXOgEC8F3wDCB-rZ81817fynT7INk"
bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands="start")
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(f"Salom, {message.from_user.full_name}")
```

**main.py file**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from aiogram import types, Dispatcher, Bot
from bot import dp, bot, TOKEN


app = FastAPI()
WEBHOOK_PATH = f"/bot/{TOKEN}"
WEBHOOK_URL = "https://7608e5642d7f.ngrok.io" + WEBHOOK_PATH


@app.on_event("startup")
async def on_startup():
    webhook_info = await bot.get_webhook_info()
    if webhook_info.url != WEBHOOK_URL:
        await bot.set_webhook(
            url=WEBHOOK_URL
        )


@app.post(WEBHOOK_PATH)
async def bot_webhook(update: dict):
    telegram_update = types.Update(**update)
    Dispatcher.set_current(dp)
    Bot.set_current(bot)
    await dp.process_update(telegram_update)


@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def on_shutdown():
    await bot.session.close()
```